# cargar ajax desde una fecha

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ajax

Necesito que un dato se me actualice en ajax pero dependiendo de la fecha seleccionada, por ejemplo, si la fecha es menor al día de hoy debe mostrar un div mostrando algo, y si supera la fecha de hoy debe mostrar otro div, actualmente solo se manejar ajax básico, les anexo el ejemplo básico (el ejemplo oficial) de ajax que es lo que se usar, alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
  <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría trabajar con Jquery para que el uso de Ajax te seria mas fácil al momento de hacer tus peticiones

```js
function loadDoc(){
  var fecha = "17/01/18";
 $("#demo").text(fecha);//Para cambiar el texto del h2 solo demostracion
  $.get( "youdomain/serviceName", { date: fecha } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    $("#demo").text(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <h2 id="demo">Let AJAX change this text</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses esto:(Si es que va a el caso)

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js">
     var fecha1 = moment();//eso es la fecha de hoy en segundos
                var fecha2 = moment(la variable de la fecha que mencionaste);//eso la fecha convertida en segundos
                var difdias = fecha1.diff(fecha2, 'days');//esto resta 
                        ambas y nos devuelve la cantidad de dias de diferencia,luego haz un if (si el numero difdias es negativo es que la fecha es superior a la de hoy con eso y lo que puso JaimeAtriano yo creo que podrias hacerlo)
```